# Parsing source code

Tags: c, parsing, yacc, lex

I need to parse the source code of different files, each written in a different language, and I would like to do this using C.

To do that, I was thinking of using `yacc` / `lex`, but I find them very hard to understand, maybe due to the complete lack of decent documentation (either that, or they really are cryptic).

So my questions are: where can I find some good documentation for `yacc` / `lex`, preferably a tutorial style introduction? Or, is there any better way to do this in C? Maybe there's something else I could use instead of `yacc` / `lex`, perhaps even written in a different language?

Comment: http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565920002 is OK.

Comment: I think you will find that learning how to use yacc and lex to be a small effort compared to building one parser for a real langauge, let alone multiple parsers.  You'd be better off simply getting parsers that are already constructed; see www.antlr.org as an option.

Comment: yacc/lex/bison/etc. are pretty much dead. I don't see the point of learning them, unless it's a pure educational pursuit. There are plenty of parser generators far better suited for the task: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators

Comment: @Gene Bushuyev, I'm very new to this field. I see tons of options and I don't know what to look for. I will most likely be parsing PHP, HTML, CSS and JavaScript, and the language in which I will implement the application will likely be C or Java. Which ones should I look at?

Comment: @Radu: here is my take on this from my personal experience, others may disagree I'm not going to argue. I don't like parser generators that come with it's own syntax and then generate code for target languages. They are maintenance nightmare, you have little similarities between lexical constructs and code, difficulties in debugging, extending, and a lot of wasted development time. I no longer use parsers that build parse trees, leaving traversals and semantics to you – poor performance, lack of expressiveness, convoluted traversal code.

Comment: My preference is a code parser generator, written in the target language. I know it works very well in C++ – excellent performance, unsurpassed flexibility, easy to debug and maintain. I don't believe you can build a good one in Java, or C#, or any scripting language. Though for a simple grammar and when performance is not an issue, many approaches will work.

Comment: @Gene, sounds good. Do you have some favorites that you could share?

Comment: @Radu: sure, I have favorites, it would be AXE, after all I've written it. I also worked a lot with its predecessor, which is an internal tool. There is also boost::Spirit, good idea, a lot of functionality, somewhat slower, and more difficult to debug. If you can't work in C++ then your options would be different. There is ANTLR, quite popular and capable, though its not my cup of tea, and AXE would beat in every case I care about. Again, go thru that list to see what suits your purposes better. I doubt very much it will be yacc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`yacc` and `lex` are very powerful tools, built around the theories for compiler construction. To be able to fully understand them you probably need some basics in formal languages, automata theory and compiler construction.

The [dragon book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers%3a_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) is a classic on the subject.

Comment: Classically bad, I would say.

Comment: Read Appendix A and ignore the rest.

Comment: Neil Butterworth: perhaps slightly off-topic, but is there some other book you prefer to the Dragon Book?

Answer (score 1):

The second half of Kernighan and Pike's *The Unix Programming Environment* is an extended introduction to programming an interpreter with lex and yacc. The lex coverage is a little light, as they mostly use a custom scanner.

Answer (score 0):

If you like math (the most important clause in this answer), then write your own compiler-compiler, and then write your compiler with that. I did this once because I was getting bored of writing all the functions for all the productions of a compiler which I had started as a recursive-descent compiler, because the available choices in 2004 didn't please me, and because I had free time while job-hunting. I only used the compiler compiler on the one project, and it is not necessarily thoroughly tested, so it is not on github. I was very happy with the grammar file syntax that I devised.

If I had such a need today I might make a different decision. The newer cutting-edge CC's seem to have have changed a lot in the last 8 years.